# Twitter Bootstrap, space between hover and dividers

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

So I have an issue with the hover and divider. Here is what I am talking about:

[image]

Basically, there is an empty background space between the hovering bg and divider. I went through the CSS but didn't manage to solve anything.

Here is the CSS: 
http://pastebin.com/Z7zvbbbP

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without your HTML markup I can only assume that you are using default `<li class="divider-vertical"></li>` for divider. In that case, divider have both left and right margins 9px each. So, to remove that space, try this:

```
.divider-vertical {
    margin: 0;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/kHAxA/

Comment: Yes, it is <li class="divider-vertical"</li> and this works. Thank you :D

Comment: This didn't work for me right away because even with this appearing lower in the page, bootstrap was still overriding my style. I had to change it to be the same granularity as bootstrap to get my style to override bootstrap, i.e. `.navbar .divider-vertical{ margin: 0; }`. Note the ".navbar" qualifier.